# Shippo ruby client - issues retrieving Shipment and rates

Tags: shippo

I am able to successfully create a shipment using the Ruby client, but when I run

`Shippo::Shipment.retrieve("valid_shipment_object_id")`

I get:

`undefined method`retrieve' for Shippo::Shipment:Class`

and when I run

`Shippo.Shipment.rates("valid_shipment_object_id")`

I get:

`undefined` method `Shipment' for Shippo:Module

I am able to run both of the above commands successfully using the same object ID using the cURL library. Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It [turns out](https://github.com/goshippo/shippo-ruby-client/issues/54) that the method for retrieving a shipment using the Ruby gem is `.get("valid_shipment_object_id")`.

Shippo's documentation is being updated accordingly, but after you use the `.get()` method, you can then access the rates using `.rates` on the Shipment object.